# Spring boot overlap of two dates

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, querydsl, localdatetime

i need solution where i need to check overlap, end-start match and start-end match
like
startDateTime=2020-10-24T11:30:34
endDateTime=2020-10-27T17:00:02

```
jpqlQuery.where(
                (
                    (start.loe(startDateTime)
                    .and(end.goe(startDateTime)))

                    .or((start.loe(endDateTime)
                    .and(end.goe(endDateTime))))

                    .or((start.loe(startDateTime)
                    .and(end.goe(endDateTime))))

                    .or((start.loe(endDateTime)
                    .and(end.goe(startDateTime))))
                    )
                );
```

need to replace where for following scenarios
Scenario      -------------------------   Result
start: 2020-10-24T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-27T17:00:02        -- false

start: 2020-10-24T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-28T17:00:02        -- false

start: 2020-10-23T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-25T17:00:02        -- false

start: 2020-10-25T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-26T17:00:02        -- false

start: 2020-10-23T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-28T17:00:02        -- false

start: 2020-10-28T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-30T17:00:02        -- true

start: 2020-10-22T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-23T17:00:02       -- true

start: 2020-10-22T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-24T11:30:34       -- true

start: 2020-10-27T17:00:02
end: 2020-10-30T17:00:02      -- true

all above scenarios should work under single where condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: i think it's not covering these cases
start: 2020-10-22T11:30:34
end: 2020-10-24T11:30:34 -- true

start: 2020-10-27T17:00:02
end: 2020-10-30T17:00:02 -- true

Comment: You have to slightly tweak the linked answer.
    If you want to find the ranges that don't overlap (excluding common limits of the ranges) then you have to:
    1) negate the `(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)` what gives ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):`(StartA > EndB) or (EndA < StartB)`.
    2) Additionally, as we include the common limits now, you have to change the inequalities to the weak ones,
    so: `(StartA >= EndB) or (EndA <= StartB)` - that is the condition we want to check

Comment: Thanks kasptom, i am done with just removing equal condition at all places, in my where condition.